# What does "authenticate with" mean?

Tags: meaning

I knew the `authenticate` means `to prove that something is real, true`. For example `The system need to authenticate the user before the user can use the system.`

But I can't understand the below example well. please help to review it.

The sentence I read is from [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1).

> In the traditional client-server authentication model, the client
> requests an access-restricted resource (protected resource) on the
> server by authenticating with the server using the resource owner's
> credentials.

What does `authenticate with` mean? Thanks.

Does it mean server provide the authenticating function to authenticate the client? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"with the server" identifies the server as the controlling authority.

Without a controlling authority in theory, you might simply compare the credentials to copies you have on paper yourself. In most cases, though, the controlling authority is self-evident from the context.

Comment: Can I just say. `authenticating in` the server? Thanks.

Comment: no, nothing is **in** the server, except hardware. You can authenticate **on** a server, but that just means that the server handles the meet and greet -- it might outsource the task of authenticating your credentials to another server, or even send an email to a person to verify your credentials

Comment: got it. you answer is little hard to understand for me. But if you say `authenticate on` example in your comments. It is better for me! Thanks.

Comment: If you want to have a loud party, you have to check *with your landlord* that it is okay, because your landlord is the controlling authority of your building. "Checking with your landlord" means you go ask him for permission. In the same way "checking with the server" or "authenticating with the server" you go ask that server for permission because that server is the controlling authority. The server may tell you yes or no as it pleases. It doesn't need to ask anyone else.

Comment: +1 For your very easy understanding example of `landlord`. Thank you. Born2Smile